# How to get rid of the virtual onscreen keyboard during login?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, gdm

After updating from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, the login screen automatically changes to only accepting the password via clicking a virtual onscreen keyboard. 
It is very inconvenient and annoying having to switch between several virtual screens simply to input a password.  I have searched online on how to disable this inconvenient feature of onscreen keyboard, but haven't found a good solution. 
Any expert here has a green thumb for this issue?

What I tried:

- settings → universal access → screen keyboard: 
  Setting the screen keyboard to "off" does not solve the above mentioned problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some more trial-error, at least this issue can be resolved as follows:

1. settings -> universal access (turn this 'universal access' to 'on' so that you get its symbol on login screen)
2. the next time you login: on the login screen, click the symbol for 'universal access', then set the 'screen keyboard' to 'off',  more importantly, also set the "Sticky keys" to 'off'. (It is possible this "Sticky key" defaults to "on", preventing one to input from keyboard.  I also set the "Slow keys" to 'off'. After that, whether the virtual keyboard appears or not is no longer an issue, since input via keyboard can now be accepted --the desired feature. Not sure why the default setting was for not-accepting keyboard input, maybe there is a reason for other users.)